# S3 move files year/month wise

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket (`s3://Bucket1`) and there are millions of files in that with format like below:

```
s3://Bucket1/yyyy-mm-dd/
```

I want to move these files like

```
s3://Bucket1/year/mm
```

Any help, script, method will be really helpful.

I have tried `aws s3 cp s3://Bucket1/ s3://Bucket1/ --include "2017-01-01*"` but this is not working good and plus I have to put extra stuff to delete files.

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1974195-copying-files-to-s3-older-than-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic steps are:

1. Get a list of objects
2. Copy the objects to the new name
3. Delete the old objects

**Get a list of objects**

Given that you have millions of files, the best way to start is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a CSV file of all the objects.

**Copy the objects to the new name**

Then, write a script that reads the CSV file and issues a **copy()** command to copy the file to the new location. This could be written in any language that has an AWS SDK (eg Python).

**Delete the old objects**

Rather than individually deleting the objects, use S3 [object lifecycle management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to delete the old files. The benefits of using this method are:

- There is no charge for the delete (whereas issuing millions of delete commands would involve a charge)
- It can be done *after* the files have been copied, providing a chance to verify that all the files have been correctly copied (by checking the next S3 inventory output)

You could use the AWS CLI to issue a `aws s3 mv` command, which will combine the copy and delete -- effectively providing a rename function. However, shell scripts aren't that easy and if things fail half-way the files will be in a mixed state. That's why I prefer the "copy all objects, and only then delete" method more.